# How do I store an image using varbinary(max) larger then 8KB with Entity Framework in MS SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

When I looked up storing images in SQL Server using Entity Framework I found that the `Image` data type is going away in SQL Server. It is suggested to use `varbinary(max)`, `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Making a `varbinary(8000)` in EF is simple enough. Just add the following line to an object.

```
public byte[] LightImage {get;set;}
```

I would like to be able to use beyond 8KB though. I've have seen people mention that it is possible to go beyond 8KB. Also it has been suggested to use a BLOB. But I don't know how to do this using Entity Framework Code first. Does anyone have an example of how to create the Entity?

Note: I am using WPF, C#, Entity Framework 6.1.1 and SQL Server 2012

Comment: Yes - use `varbinary(max)` which gives you **up to 2 GB** of storage - for every single column! No change needed in your EF code, it's just a large byte array ...

Comment: Okay, I was confused when I read the documentation I thought it had a limit of 8000 Bytes. I was able to save using a PNGBitmapEncoder, but I have yet to try and retrieve the file. But i'm sure it will work smoothly.